# Ember: Cannot read property 'modelName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, sails.js, ember-cli

We are using `ember 1.13.5`, `ember-data 1.13.7` and `sails 0.11` for the backend.

The full error is: `Cannot read property 'modelName' of undefined at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.serializerFor`

I followed the code through dev-tools and came to the code shown in the image below. It shows that `modelName` is defined.

[image]

This is the actually code that is being called in my `setup.js` controller:

```
_this.store.query('business-account', {user: user.get('id')})
      .then(function(businessAccount) {
        debugger;
      }, function(err) {
        debugger;
      });
```

The above throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelName' of undefined
at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.serializerFor (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:83513:35)
at https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:106657:34
at https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:86465:20
at Map.forEach.cb (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:27626:11)
at OrderedSet.forEach (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:27409:11)
at Map.forEach (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:27630:18)
at Function.ember$data$lib$system$model$$default.reopenClass.eachRelationship (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:86464:83)
at DS.default.RESTSerializer.extend._extractEmbeddedRecords (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:106650:12)
at DS.default.RESTSerializer.extend.normalize (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:106635:19)
at apply (https://192.168.10.10:4200/assets/vendor-844725f1b0311e7dd3df737ef28a9edc.js:32729:18)
```

**UPDATE:**

I also have a model named `businessAccount`

`app/models/business-account.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

    /////////////////////////////
  // ASSOCIATIONS 
  /////////////////////////////

  business: DS.belongsTo('business', { async: true }),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),

  /////////////////////////////
  // ATTRIBUTES
  /////////////////////////////

  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  kind: DS.attr('string'),
  ROP: DS.attr('string'),
  ssn: DS.attr('string'),
  biography: DS.attr('string'),
  totalPaidToDate: DS.attr('number'),
  phoneNumbers: DS.attr('string'),
  oneWordDescriptions: DS.attr('string'),
  modesOfTransport: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string'),
  availabilities: DS.attr('string'),
  exclusionTImes: DS.attr('string')
});
```

`business.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

  /////////////////////////////
  // ASSOCIATIONS 
  /////////////////////////////

    businessAccounts: DS.hasMany('businessAccount', { async: true }),

  /////////////////////////////
  // ATTRIBUTES
  /////////////////////////////

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  legalBusinessName: DS.attr('string'),
  timezone: DS.attr('string'),
  emails: DS.attr('string'),
  phoneNumbers: DS.attr('string'),
  availabilities: DS.attr('string'),
  exclusionTimes: DS.attr('string'),
  holidays: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string')

});
```

`user.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

  /////////////////////////////
  // ASSOCIATIONS 
  /////////////////////////////

  businessAccounts: DS.hasMany('businessAccount', { async: true }),

  /////////////////////////////
  // ATTRIBUTES
  /////////////////////////////

  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  phoneNumbers: DS.attr('string'),
  secondaryContactInfo: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string')

});
```

`json` response from sails:

```
    [
  {
    "business": {
      "name": "businessName",
      "ein": null,
      "website": null,
      "primaryContact": null,
      "bankInformation": null,
      "legalBusinessName": null,
      "timezone": null,
      "emails": null,
      "phoneNumbers": null,
      "availabilities": null,
      "exclusionTimes": null,
      "holidays": null,
      "address": null,
      "archived": false,
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2015-07-31T11:22:26.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2015-07-31T11:22:26.000Z"
    },
    "user": {
      "firstName": "Monty",
      "lastName": "Lennie",
      "email": null,
      "phoneNumbers": null,
      "secondaryContactInfo": null,
      "address": null,
      "archived": false,
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2015-07-31T11:22:25.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2015-07-31T11:22:25.000Z",
      "auth": 1
    },
    "status": null,
    "kind": null,
    "active": false,
    "ROP": null,
    "ssn": null,
    "biography": null,
    "totalPaidToDate": null,
    "phoneNumbers": null,
    "oneWordDescriptions": null,
    "modesOfTransport": null,
    "address": null,
    "availabilities": null,
    "exclusionTimes": null,
    "archived": false,
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2015-07-31T11:22:26.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-31T11:22:26.000Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you have a model named business-account?

Comment: @Kitler yes I do I just updated the question with it.

Comment: Are the associations models present as well?

Comment: What's the JSON response?

Comment: @Kitler yeah the association model is missing a hasMany line. I'll add that and see if it works.

Comment: @kilter actually it turns out they were there I just updated the question to show them

Comment: @Kingpin2k Ok I added the json response to the question. The associations are not being side-loaded properly but I don't think that should cause the current bug?